# Decoding \\uXXXX characters

Tags: c#

I have an HTML-encoded URI with percent-encoded characters. I then have JS-encoding done on the same string using `HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode`. I would like to decode the JavaScript encoded URI without affecting the percent-encoded characters.

I have tried `HttpUtility.UrlDecode` but that decodes everything. Specifically JS encoding produces \uXXXX characters that I would like to decode.

Comment: Code & exemple are welcome...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are sure there's no other "escaped characters", you could use [Regex.Unescape](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.unescape%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

That should do the trick, just make sure there are no other "\"-escaped characters in the string.

Demonstrating fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/LdA5cF (notice the string is verbatim, so it is not escaped by `Console.WriteLine`)